# I get a list out of range

Tags: python, list, class, range

```
class Spillebrett:
    def __init__ (self, rader, kolonner):
        self._rader=rader
        self._kolonner=kolonner
        self._rutenett=[[]]

    def generer(self):
        for i in range(self._rader):
            for j in range(self._kolonner):
                rand=randint(0,3)
                if rand==3:
                    self._rutenett[i][j].settLevende()
```

> File "/mnt/c/skole/Oblig7/spillebrett.py", line 78, in generer
>       self._rutenett[i][j].settLevende() IndexError: list index out of range

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are creating new lists in self._rutenett

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simple example:

```
item1 = 5
item2 = 5

newlist = []

for i in range(item1):
    newlist.append([])
    for j in range(item2):
        newlist[i].append((i,j))

newlist
```

Returns:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)],
 [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)],
 [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)],
 [(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]]
```

We can also use list comprehension to achieve the same thing:

```
item1 = 5
item2 = 5

newlist = [[(i,j) for j in range(item2)] for i in range(item1)]

newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `self._rutenett` is an empty list of lists it is `self._rutenett[i][j]` is out of range.

Uses `self._rutenett.append()` to add non-existent members to lists, (note that you can't have a sparse list, i.e. one with an index of 2 without 0 & 1 existing use a dictionary *or better a `collections.defaultdict`* for that).